# reading return code from bash script to bash script?

Tags: bash

I have the following snippet working such that my bash script exits early on failure

```
./gradlew clean build release
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Successfully BUILT FAKE RELEASE"
else
  echo "BUILDING FAKE RELEASE FAILED"
  exit $?
fi
```

I see the failure log statement BUT my script that calls it continues on instead of exiting and in that script, I have pretty much the same code

```
./runAllTesting.sh
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Successfully RAN ALL TESTING"
else
  echo "TESTING SYSTEM Failed(don't release this)"
  exit $?
fi
```

What am I doing wrong here?  This is on 10.11.6 el capitan mac computer.

Comment: I think `$?` in the `exit` parameter will always return success because the command preceding it is `echo`, which will always succeed

Comment: oh crap, lol, duh me. @KoCour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my script that calls it continues on

Yes, you should check your snippet‘s exit code in the calling script, then behave accordingly

```
if ! ./posted_snippet.sh; then
  exit
fi
```

In this way the top level exits, but loses the information about the error code which caused it to exit. It is often irrelevant, because error messages from `posted_snippet.sh` would make clear which test failed and why. However, if that error code has to be passed to the upper level, one could use the concise form

```
./posted_snippet.sh || exit $?
```

which is way better than `if ./posted_snippet.sh; then :; else exit $?; fi`.

What is crucial is that `posted_snippet.sh` should exit with the correct code, and it has already been pointed out in the comments that it doesn’t. Your last `$?` captures the exit code of `echo`, which is always 0. Here is a working version:

```
./runAllTesting.sh
test_result=$?
if [ $test_result -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Successfully RAN ALL TESTING"
else
  echo "TESTING SYSTEM Failed(don't release this)"
  exit $test_result
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

`$?` means what is the exit status of the last command that was executed. The last command that was executed is `echo "TESTING SYSTEM Failed(don't release this)"` and it ran successfully. What you were really doing after that echo statement was `exit 0`. The workaround is to save `$?` in a variable

```
./gradlew clean build release
readonly status=$?
if [[ $status -eq 0 ]];then
  echo "Successfully BUILT FAKE RELEASE"
else
  echo "BUILDING FAKE RELEASE FAILED"
  exit $status
fi
```

The above solution won't work if and only if you are executing the if conditional statement in a child process inside your script

Comment: so the value might not get overwritten

Comment: Overwritten by who?